# Song playing in Kanon (2006) episode 8

Tags: music, kanon

I would like to know what song plays in episode 8 (The Fantasia of Reminiscence
〜fantasie〜) of Kanon (2006) anime starting around 12:50 when snow starts to fall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That song is called "Yume no Ato", which means "After the Dream". It's Track 2 of the *Kanon* original soundtrack, which I was pleasantly surprised to find can be purchased [on iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/kanon-original-soundtrack/id813627592), along with lots of other great anime music (including the OSTs for *Clannad*, *Little Busters*, *Charlotte*, *Angel Beats*, *Planetarian*, and *Rewrite*).